# Comparing statistical difference between two trendlines/slopes

Tags: anova, linear, biostatistics

I was involved in bench testing for a medical device from 2 companies. How much one end of the device can rotate (0 to 180 deg) translates to rotation at the opposite end (0 to 180 deg) was measured. On a table it would look like:

Input angle: 0, 45, 90, 135, 180
Output angle: 0, 40, 88, 132, 178

This is repeated for 10 devices from each company. Plotting it on a graph would have the x-axis as input angle and y-axis would be output angle. We want to demonstrate a 1:1 (slope of 1) for one device, and to test if the slope of the other device is significantly different.

What statistical test can be performed here to evaluate if there is a statistical difference between both slopes? Or is there another way to evaluate for significant differences?

Answer (score 1):

You can test for this using a linear model (or various flavors of ANOVA that use the same underlying model). What I'm going to say assumes the slope is in fact linear - what you hope to show - and that the residual errors in your output angles follow a normal distribution. I am not sure whether the latter is appropriate or not, perhaps the errors are bigger around 90° than they are elsewhere, but it is something you can check for after fitting the model.

##### Linear regression

The most basic model you want to fit is a line through the input-output angle pairs, while allowing the slope of that line to differ between devices. From this model you can then draw inference on whether the slopes are equal or not.

I'll illustrate with an example in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), first we simulate some data where the devices are equal:

```
set.seed(1)

angle_in <- c(0, 45, 90, 135, 180)
angles <- length(angle_in)
samples_per_angle <- 5
n <- angles * samples_per_angle

## Add a random error term to all observations, note that it is the same everywhere
angle_out_x <- rep(angle_in, each=samples_per_angle) + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=3)
angle_out_y <- rep(angle_in, each=samples_per_angle) + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=3)
```

This gives us the following data, which should look similar (hopefully!) to yours. The two devices are color-coded, but again, they are identical apart from random error right now.
[image: simulated data with only random error]

Let's fit a linear model, where we allow the slope between input and output angle to *interact* with the device type (this will effectively give us a slope parameter per device):

```
df <- data.frame(
  device = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = n),
  angle_in = rep(rep(angle_in, each = samples_per_angle), 2),
  angle_out = c(angle_out_x, angle_out_y)
)

summary(fit <- lm(angle_out ~ angle_in + angle_in:device, data=df))

> Coefficients:
>                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)      -0.1156901  0.6192023  -0.187    0.853    
> angle_in          1.0051125  0.0064865 154.953   <2e-16 ***
> angle_in:deviceY -0.0009576  0.0064865  -0.148    0.883    
> 
> Residual standard error: 2.528 on 47 degrees of freedom
```

Our model has three parameters whose values are shown in the coefficient estimates: the intercept is the estimated value for `angle_out` when `angle_in` is zero - note that we have explicitly assumed this to be the same for all devices right now. The next two parameters express the slope for the reference device (in our case device `X`, because R picks the first category by default) and the *difference* in slope for the non-reference device(s). This last parameter directly provides a test for equality in slopes between both devices, and what do you know: there's very little evidence to say that they aren't equal (absolute difference is below 0.001, *P*=0.883). Exactly what we put in by design!

The only thing missing is a test for the device `X` slope being 1, the current hypothesis tests for the coefficients compare against 0. The `summary` method won't give us the desired test as far as I know but there's ways around that:

```
## Option 1: do a t-test manually, comparing the estimate vs. 1
2*pt(-abs((1.0051125 - 1) / 0.0064865), df=47)
> 0.4345515

## Option 2: use external package (other options may exist)
car::linearHypothesis(fit, "angle_in = 1")
>   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
>       47 300.34  1    3.9697 0.6212 0.4346
```

Both tests give *P*=0.4346 for the slope being different from 1, so we don't reject that either.

##### Unequal slopes

It's obviously more interesting to see whether we can also detect if the slopes are *not* equal. Back to our simulated data, let's tweak device `Y` a bit:

```
set.seed(1)

slope_y <- rep(angle_in, each=samples_per_angle) * 0.1
angle_out_y2 <- rep(angle_in, each=samples_per_angle) + rnorm(n, mean=slope_y, sd=3)
```

[image: simulated data with unequal slopes]

Throwing this into the model (using very similar code as before) gives these coefficients:

```
>                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)      0.368984   0.705148   0.523    0.603    
> angle_in         1.001522   0.007387 135.581   <2e-16 ***
> angle_in:deviceY 0.100000   0.007387  13.538   <2e-16 ***
```

The estimated difference in slope is now 0.10 (*P*<0.0001), again exactly as we designed it - but the model didn't know that!

##### Going further

The above was already quite a lot of text for a basic linear regression for which there should be plenty of other tutorials out there, so I'm only briefly going to touch on some other ideas:

- **Unequal intercepts**: as mentioned the current model fixes the intercept at the same value for all devices, this may or may not be reasonable as you seemed to be most interested in the slope. You can add extra parameters and perform similar tests for intercepts which you would expect to be 0.
- **Goodness of fit**: you'll want to check if your model fit is adequate, using e.g. `plot(fit)` will get you started graphically. It doesn't make much sense to do this in my simulations because they follow the model assumptions by design.
- **Measurement scale**: a bit of a catch-all related to goodness-of-fit, I'm not sure if your measurements in degrees (or their conditional errors) necessarily follow a normal distribution. This will matter less the more observations you have. You might want to transform variables and/or look into generalized linear models if the linearity-normality assumptions don't seem to hold, but you'd have to carefully examine your data to determine what makes sense here. I would certainly recommend *against* transforming 'just because you like the result better'.